# Individually Addressable LED overheated

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiring, short-circuit, led-strip, ws2812b

## Update (19.3.24)

I checked the LED string with a multimeter. The + and - wire of the burned LEDs are connected, whereas the new LEDs do not have a connection between the + and - wires.

I checked the barrel jack as well, the + and - poles are not inverted.

## (18.3.24)

Sadly, even with the right power supply, the LEDs still break and create fumes. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

## (16.3.24)

Firstly, I wanted to thank you all for your inputs. Indeed, the cause of my issue turned out to be an overcurrent. Thanks to your comments I went back to the electronics shop that sold the power supply to me, and we realized that the supply was **labeled wrongly**. The producer labeled the supply as 5V 4A, even though it was **15V 1.6A**. This was most likely the main issue, I will try out the same setup with the correct current later and update, if it works. Thanks again for your help! :)

---

I'm trying to build an LED-cube using string lights and a raspberry pi 4. I followed along [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/aNlaj1r7NKc?si=woN2FkGovFZD5Gf5&t=595), in which the RGB WS2812B strip has 5 wires going into it: two red (power) wires, one for external power and one for the raspberry pi as a power source. Then, two white (ground) wires, so the power supply and the raspberry share a common ground. Lastly, one green (data) cable.

The [LEDs I ordered](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005005614316173.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.24.636e5c5fJbYAju&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu) only have three wires, though. A power, data and ground wire. I figured that by soldering the wires, I could reach the same hardware setup like in the tutorial.

I wasn't sure how to connect the two ground cables, so I twisted them and screwed them into the barrel jack.

[image: Wiring from tutorial]

[image: My wiring diagram]

[image: Wiring into the Raspberry Pi]

[image: Barrel Jack wiring]

[image: Connection to LEDs]

I tried this setup three times, each time thinking that I did a bad job soldering or I did something wrong when powering the LEDs. Each time I only powered 10 LEDs. Keep in mind that during my attempts I did not run a single line of code one the raspberry pi.

On attempt one the LEDs blinked in irregular intervals, but slowly started to loose light.
On attempt two I powered the LEDs and the Raspberry Pi at the same time, which lead to a short circuit. On attempt three I powered the LEDs first. Again, the LEDs blinked, but not all of them. As soon as the Raspberry Pi was booted, there was another short circuit. This time I noticed that one LED was particularly hot and had burned the plastic surrounding it.

[image]

I'm really new to all of this, so I believe that I might have done something wrong with the wiring. I ruled out the power supply, since the 5V 4A DC power supply complies with the instructions given by the tutorial and the product specification of the LED lights. I think the ground connection I did is the problem here, but again, I'm not sure. I don't understand why I cannot wire it the way I did.

The other possibility is that the LEDs are bad, but I do not have any way to know this. Can someone explain why my LEDs overheated? Great thanks!

Comment: Have you checked (again again :-) ) that +5 and ground have not been swapped?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Hi, thanks for your reply. I lost count of how many times I've checked. The red (+5V) wire is connected to the plus pole of the barrel jack. The white (ground) wire is connected to the minus pole of the barrel jack. The red wire is also only connected to the Led lights, whereas the white wire is connected to the raspi, the barrel jack and the lights.

Comment: "_connected to the plus pole of the barrel jack. [...] is connected to the minus pole of the barrel jack_" have you measured the terminals with a multimeter to confirm that they are labelled correctly?

Comment: Concerning your barrel jack, is it the type where ground is on the outside(i.e. ring of metal) or on the inside(shrouded plug)? The SMPS in question should label which contact is ground, and which one is +5V. From the picture and descriptions, this sounds like polarity reversal(or much less likely, resistor failure i.e. overcurrent).

Comment: @Attie Thanks for your help, I haven't considered that the barrel jack could be labelled incorrectly, will check!

Comment: @lemon I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly and I couldn't find any information in the [manual](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=GST25E)

Comment: @TLB - for more context, they are _generally (but not always!)_ center positive. It should be marked on the power supply somewhere, but the connection from the socket to terminal block could be the less common variant too.

Comment: @lemon, I checked the power supply and it turned out that it was labeled wrongly. It was not a 5V 4A Supply, but rather 15V 1.6A. I updated the question for that reason. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: If you actually gave them 15v then all of the LEDs are dead. But 15v doesn't seem too likely. Why do you think the power supply was incorrect?

Comment: @user1850479 I had my suspicions that I may have bought the wrong power supply, because I couldn't find anything wrong with the barrel jack nor the LEDs. I went back to the electronics shop and they told me that they've had the same issue with their supplier multiplier. They confirmed to me that the power supply was indeed 15V and not 5V, as it was labeled. I haven't tried powering the previous LEDs a second, so I don't know if they still work. I just know that one led burned, and most likely all the other one's are also broken

Comment: They MAY not all be dead with 15V having been applied. If you are lucky the first short may have loaded the power supply enough to save the others. Or not :-(

Comment: **IF** these are LEDs that have had 15V applied then they may now not work on 5V. IF they have not had 15V applied then ??? || Have the LEDs that now die ever had 15V applied?

Comment: @RusselMcMahon every time I tried to power the LEDs, I cut an unused string off. So the LEDs are always unused.

Comment: We have identified a couple problems:  incorrect voltage and failing to turn the LEDs on.  You're now saying you fixed the incorrect voltage, but if you plug in the device and don't turn it on it burns up.  Are you sure you fixed the incorrect voltage?  Tried measuring the voltage you're supplying to the strip and verified it matches the spec?

Comment: Is it possible that the identification of which lead is which for the LED strip is wrong? It seems unlikely, but   ... >

Comment: @user1850479 Hi, thanks, i tried it again, now only with 3 LEDs, I also triple checked that there is no direct connection between the plus and minus wire with the multi meter. This time I could plug in the LEDs to the power source without the LEDs burning and breaking. I also check the current is actually V5, and this seems to be the case. But when I wanted to run the script on the raspberry pi, the LEDs didn't light up. I'm guessing that this is more of a software question than a electronics one, since I asked the supplier an they told me I should use the ws2811 protocol instead of the ws2812

Answer (score 1):

WS2812 does not work without programming. At the moment the power is on, it may get some random pulses, which chips may interpret as data. But the result is irrelevant. Your setup looks OK. Big possibility the strip is damaged.
To get 5 wires instead of 3 just +5V and -5V can be split. Also current consumption should be kept in mind. WS2812 one chip may consume 60mA at full brightness all 3 colours.

Comment: Can you clarify your "_-5v_" ...?

Comment: @attie it is white wire In that case. In common, DC power supply output has two poles,"+" and "-".

Comment: The majority of DC power supplies are positive only (e.g: `+5v` and `0v`), and not split rail (`+5v`, `0v` and `-5v`)... in this situation, `+` and `-` generally do not denote `+5v` and `-5v` (i.e: `10v` potential difference), but rather `+5v` and `0v`. Clarity here is important.

Comment: @attie if you take a look at the picture with DC adapter, signs"+" and "-" can be seen. Most unipolar DC power supplies outputs marked + and -..

Comment: Correct, but that does _not_ make it -5v! It's an abbreviation of "_positive_" (`+`) and "_negative_" (`-`) which are relative terms.